# Three non-linear equations with three variables, how can I know if one variable is redundant?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I was wondering if I could get some references for my problem.

I have three highly non-linear equations:

$$f_{1}(x,y,z) = 0$$

$$f_{2}(x,y,z) = 0$$

$$f_{3}(x,y,z) = 0$$

I want to see if the variable $z$ is not redundant. For instance, after rearranging the three equations, if I'm in a situation where

$$\tilde{f}_{1}(x,y) = 0$$

$$\tilde{f}_{2}(x,y) = 0$$

$$x+y+z = 0$$

then, $z$ naturally follows from $(x^{*},y^{*})$ that solves the first two equations.

What would be the steps to examine this issue numerically? I thought this was related to the rank problem, but I couldn't find more. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

---

Maybe I was unclear about what I meant by "redundant". I wanted to say a variable that can be directly inferred from the other variables.

Comment: Looking at your final form, why do you think $z$ is redundant? The solution is not invariant with respect to $z$

Comment: [[1]] Variables can not be redundant. [[2]] Out of the 3 Equations , 1 Equation (not variable) might be redundant [[3]] It might occur that 1 Equation is Inconsistent with the other 2 Equations.

Comment: You are thinking of an "implicit function". That is, having a map $F : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$. (In your case $F(x,y,z) = (f_1(x,y,z), f_2(x,y,z), f_3(x,y,z))$.) And you want to know when $F(x,y,z) = 0$ allows you to define $z$ as a function of $(x,y)$. Evaluating this is going to depend on the characteristics of your functions $f_i$. If they are continuously differentiable, then you can use the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).